# Calculate sum of intervals in a column based on a seperate column

Tags: r, dataframe, vectorization

I have a dataframe `df` that looks something like this:

```
     X1         X2
1     0 0.06174568
2     0 0.06174568
3     0 0.05978832
4     0 0.05978832
5     0 0.06007480
      ...
22    0 0.06082051
23    0 0.06051641
24  128 0.06329613
25    0 0.06099445
26    0 0.06195348
27    0 0.06022723
28    0 0.06041903
29    0 0.06195348
      ...
36    0 0.06195348
37    0 0.06176168
38    0 0.06233710
39  103 0.06195348
40    0 0.06195348
41    0 0.06387155
42    0 0.06291252
```

I'd like to sum up the values of `X2` until `X1 != 0`, i.e. the rows 1-24 and 25-39. The sums should be added in a different column `X3`:

```
     X1         X2        X3
1     0 0.06174568 0.0000000
2     0 0.06174568 0.0000000
3     0 0.05978832 0.0000000
4     0 0.05978832 0.0000000
5     0 0.06007480 0.0000000
           ...
22    0 0.06082051 0.0000000
23    0 0.06051641 0.0000000
24  128 0.06329613 1.4660679
25    0 0.06099445 0.0000000
26    0 0.06195348 0.0000000
27    0 0.06022723 0.0000000
28    0 0.06041903 0.0000000
29    0 0.06195348 0.0000000
           ...
36    0 0.06195348 0.0000000
37    0 0.06176168 0.0000000
38    0 0.06233710 0.0000000
39  103 0.06195348 0.9876114
40    0 0.06195348 0.0000000
41    0 0.06387155 0.0000000
```

It's easy to solve using a for-loop:

```
j <- 1
df$X3 <- numeric(NROW(df))

for (i in 1:NROW(df)) {
  if (df$X1[i] != 0) {
    df$X3[i] <- sum(df$X2[j:i])
    j <- i
  }
}
```

But I was wondering if there was a way to calculate these sums without using a loop, possibly by using `apply()`?

Heres the sample dataframe:

```
structure(list(X1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 103, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X2 = c(0.0617456756756757, 
0.0617456756756757, 0.0597883157894737, 0.0597883157894737, 0.0600748, 
0.0611470588235294, 0.0611470588235294, 0.0599241176470588, 0.0606791111111111, 
0.0628226666666667, 0.0599241176470588, 0.0619248571428571, 0.0613493684210526, 
0.0613493684210526, 0.0620369230769231, 0.0594520512820513, 0.0620369230769231, 
0.0608205128205128, 0.0615807692307692, 0.0612766666666667, 0.0608205128205128, 
0.0608205128205128, 0.0605164102564103, 0.0632961290322581, 0.0609944516129032, 
0.0619534838709678, 0.0602272258064516, 0.0604190322580645, 0.0619534838709678, 
0.0623370967741936, 0.0617616774193548, 0.061378064516129, 0.0619534838709678, 
0.0619534838709678, 0.061378064516129, 0.0619534838709678, 0.0617616774193548, 
0.0623370967741936, 0.0619534838709678, 0.0619534838709678, 0.0638715483870968, 
0.0629125161290323, 0.0629125161290323, 0.0629125161290323, 0.0636797419354839, 
0.0638715483870968, 0.0632961290322581, 0.0623370967741936, 0.0652141935483871, 
0.0650223870967742, 0.0632961290322581, 0.0608026451612903, 0.0615698709677419, 
0.0632961290322581, 0.0608604848484849, 0.0648218181818182, 0.0614006666666667, 
0.0596390196078431, 0.0604162926829268, 0.0608205128205128, 0.0608205128205128, 
0.0608205128205128, 0.0595836164383562, 0.0589412054794521, 0.0599826829268293, 
0.0598381463414634, 0.0599826829268293, 0.0598381463414634, 0.0599826829268293, 
0.0599826829268293, 0.0598381463414634, 0.0606138, 0.0598728, 
0.0597246, 0.0597246, 0.0594282, 0.0595764, 0.0601692, 0.0598728, 
0.060021, 0.04617, 0.04617, 0.046398, 0.0603174, 0.0601692, 0.0597246, 
0.0603174, 0.0594282, 0.060021, 0.0601692, 0.0602123076923077, 
0.0606684615384615, 0.0597561538461538, 0.0601005263157895, 0.0607249473684211, 
0.0607249473684211, 0.0600988235294118, 0.0602735294117647, 0.0606229411764706, 
0.0602735294117647, 0.0599241176470588, 0.0614964705882353, 0.0606229411764706, 
0.0606229411764706, 0.0602282857142857, 0.0614158857142857, 0.0602282857142857, 
0.0605676, 0.0598889714285714, 0.0602282857142857, 0.0604713333333333, 
0.0608678666666667, 0.0604713333333333, 0.0600748, 0.0602730666666667, 
0.0602730666666667, 0.0601692, 0.0601692, 0.0598728, 0.0601692, 
0.0601692, 0.0598728, 0.064768, 0.064592, 0.064416, 0.06424, 
0.06424, 0.0642292, 0.0642292, 0.0642292, 0.0647038, 0.0643874, 
0.065026, 0.06403475, 0.06443125, 0.064233, 0.06522425, 0.06443125, 
0.06562075, 0.065026, 0.06443125, 0.06443125, 0.0603493333333333, 
0.0603493333333333, 0.0600195555555556, 0.0603493333333333, 0.0601844444444445, 
0.0601844444444445, 0.0646295, 0.06522425, 0.065026, 0.06522425, 
0.06443125, 0.06443125, 0.0699253333333334, 0.0701013333333333, 
0.0701013333333333, 0.0693973333333333, 0.0697493333333333, 0.0704533333333334, 
0.0699253333333334, 0.0699253333333334, 0.0695733333333333, 0.0697493333333333, 
0.0695997142857143, 0.0701429714285714, 0.0694186285714286, 0.0699618857142857, 
0.0603493333333333, 0.0605142222222222, 0.0610088888888889, 0.0605142222222222, 
0.0606791111111111, 0.0605142222222222)), .Names = c("X1", "X2"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 174L))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We create a group using `cumsum` and then do the `sum`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(grp = lag(cumsum(X1 !=0), default = 0)) %>% 
    mutate(X3 = replace(rep(sum(X2),n()),  X1==0, 0))
```

Comment: Nice one, didn't know you could define grp within group_by. Also, congrats on 300K :)

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

With base R, you could combine `ave` and `pmin` to get the result.

```
dat$x3 <- pmin(dat$X1, ave(dat$X2, cumsum(c(0, diff(dat$X1) < 0)), FUN=function(x) sum(x)))
```

Groups are constructed by calculating the difference in X1 and incrementing when it is negative. Note that this assumes, as in the example that the deviations from zero in X1 are always positive. If this is not the case, then you could replace `dat$X1` with `abs(dat$X1)`.

The zero values in the new variable are set to zero by using a `pmin` comparison. I may be faster to use math operations like

```
dat$x3 <- ave(dat$X2, cumsum(c(0, diff(dat$X1) < 0)), FUN=function(x) sum(x)) * sign(dat$X1)
```